# How do I print the argument name as a string i

Tags: python

I am checking the data type of several arguments in a function. If one of them is the wrong type, I want an error to be raised, that says:

> TypeError: Argument my_arg did not receive a string!

For instance:

```
def function(a, b, c, d):
    for arg in [a, b, c, d]:
        if not isinstance(arg, str):
            raise TypeError(f'Argument {"<some arg>"} did not receive a string!')
```

```
function(a='djsoa', b='sajdjsld', c='dsaa', d=10)
```

How can this be done? Please note that using a dict for arguments is not possible for me.

Comment: Why is it not possible exactly? Would `def function(**kwargs)` counts as "dict for arguments"?

Comment: A value doesn't have an associated name. And the variable the value is assigned to changes too. You can't trace `arg` back to `a`. You will need to use a dict or something comparable *somewhere*.

Comment: See the marked duplicate for how to access and inspect the function's arguments.  You'll need to change your loop header.  Iterate over the parameters; access and check the type of each value.  That way, when you hit an error, you'll have the parameter name handy.

Comment: I guess I could just zip it with the arg name as a string